# Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to retrive value as below :

```
    string server = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME");
    //Declare the form being accessed ex: Default.aspx
    string url = Request.ServerVariables("URL");
    // Declare the query string in the URL
    string querystring = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING");
```

But I got a error :

> Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables' cannot be used like a method.

Please help to find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: While the server name needs to be extracted this way, ASP.Net will automatically parse the query string and URL for you. So rather than writing your own parsing code, rely on the framework and use `Request.QueryString` and `Request.Url` instead. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d5940ad.aspx)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are trying to get it in VB.Net like way. You have to use `[] instead of ()` . In C# `[]` is used while in the VB.Net `()` is used. e.g.

```
string server = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
string url = Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
querystring = Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"];
```

Comment: Muhaammad @ Thanks i got a solun.

Comment: @Jason i m new in stackoverflow.I dont know how to accept it.plz guide me.

Comment: Square brackets is what I was missing ... converting from VB.net

Answer (score 4):

Its a hash not a method. Replace () with []